# Google Jquery Min vs Jquery 2

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if there was any differences in the Google Ajax Jquery?

I'm using, this to get a virtual (Korean) keyboard to work...

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The problem is if I use that it breaks a lot of my other Jquery code (certain buttons are no longer clickable and such) but as soon as I remove it and use my downloaded Jquery file then the keyboard and Korean input no longer works but the rest of my site does.

Comment: Yes, jQuery 1.6.2 is quite different from jQuery 2.

Comment: Travel back through the [jQuery blog](http://blog.jquery.com/category/jquery/) to see what changes arrived with each new version. Here's [jQuery 1.6.2](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/06/30/jquery-162-released/) to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Google (and others) have multiple versions of jQuery hosted on their CDN.  You should check the page and link to the specific version you need:

https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery